# viewmodel is runing multiple in compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

i was checking my debug and i see my ViewModel or screen run multi time

my viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class DownloadViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DataRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val downloadList: LiveData<List<DownloadModel>> = repository.getDownload().asLiveData()
```

my screen

```
@Composable
fun TetsScreen(dm : DownloadViewModel){
    Log.e("is running", "true")
    val downloads by dm.downloadList.observeAsState()
    
Column(modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.White)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
if (downloads.isNullOrEmpty()){
        //to do
    }else{
        Log.e("its", "work")
    }
 }
```

my NavHost

val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = AppScreens.MainScreen.name){

```
    composable(AppScreens.TestScreen.name){
        TetsScreen(downloadViewModel)
    }
    composable(AppScreens.MainScreen.name){
        MainScreen(navController = navController, userViewModel, profileViewModel, downloadViewModel)
    }
```

for starting new Screen

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){

                navController.navigate(AppScreens.TestScreen.name) {
                    popUpTo(AppScreens.MainScreen.name) { inclusive = true}
                }
            }
```

and my debug

```
E/is running: true
E/is running: true
E/is running: true
E/its: work
E/is running: true
E/its: work
E/its: work
```

but when i remove

```
val downloads = dm.downloadList.observeAsState()
```

everything will be normal

i try start screen without LaunchedEffect but nothing change

please if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually your view model, as you're collecting data from LiveData, everytime you get an update (regardless of it's content), compose detects it and gets refreshed on every new observed data change, that's why you see your Log on every re-composition as "E/is running: true" until some data it's succesfully loaded and finally shows you a "E/is running: true" followed by a Log of "E/its: work".

Comment: so you mean its normal?